# Prove form of solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

I have a statement $W$ about a natural number $n$. I know that $W$ is false for even numbers, and I was able to prove that $W(n) \iff W(2n+1)$, and I already know that $W(1)$ is true. Intuition tells me that the only values of $n$ for which $W$ holds are given by $1,3,7,15,...,2^k-1,...$, and the first few numbers are in fact the only numbers I have found that work, but how do I prove this formally?

It might be helpful to know that the proof that $W(2n+1)$ resolves into proving $W(n)$.

Comment: It doesn't hold for all properties $W$on the odd natural numbers, for instance let $W(n)$ be predicate $n\text{ is an odd natural number}$. Then certainly $\forall n\in \mathbb N\left(W(n) \iff W(2n+1)\right)$ holds and so does $W(5)$.

Comment: I am slightly puzzled by the fact that $W(n)$ is only defined for odd $n$. So have you proved that *if $n$ is odd, then $W(n) \iff W(2n+1)$*, or something else, like *if $W(2n+1)$ holds, then $n$ is odd, and...*

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I know as a fact that $W$ is false for even numbers.

Comment: @shardulc Your response to my comment is more appropriate as a comment. Please leave it as a comment and I'll reply.

Comment: I don't think that can happen in my case because the proof that $W(2n+1)$ resolves into proving $W(n)$. The proof of your example, that a given number is odd, does not depend on previous numbers at all.

Comment: @shardulc You have that $\forall n\in \mathbb N(\neg W(2n))$ and $\forall n\in \mathbb N(n\text{ is odd}\implies (W(n)\iff W(2n+1)))$. You claim that $\forall n\in \mathbb N(W(n)\text{ is true}\implies\exists k\in \mathbb N(n=2^k-1))$. What I mentioned is a counter example to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will prove by induction that $W(m)$ holds only for $m = 2^{k}-1$, for some $k > 0$.

Suppose we have proved this up to $m = 2^{k-1} - 1$, the basis being provided by the case $k=1$.

Let $2^{k-1} - 1 < m \le 2^{k} - 1$, with $m = 2 n + 1$ odd. If $W(m)$ holds, then $W(n)$ holds, with 
$$
n = \frac{m-1}{2}.
$$
But then
$$
2^{k-2} - 1 < n \le 2^{k-1} - 1,
$$
and then by induction $n = 2^{k-1} - 1$, so that $m = 2 n + 1 = 2^{k} - 2 + 1 = 2^{k} - 1$.

Comment: This uses the second principle of induction, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed, that form of the principle.